# Rails - Multiple Layouts Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout

I have more than 1 app that are exaclty the same. The only difference is the layout of these apps. I was looking for a way that I could change the layout based on what Iḿ going to use. Example: if I seed my database with male stuff, the app will have to use the male layout. The same happens if I seed with female data.

In my searchs I have found the `nested layouts` and even some theme generators gens, that I don't think will actually work since I already have the layouts made.

Any one has any new idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given you know how to detect what layout to load, something like this should work:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :choose_layout

  protected
    def choose_layout
      *your male/female logic* ? "male" : "female"
    end

end
```

[rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)